# Apache - Adding Redirect to sub-directory V/S changing DocumentRoot

Tags: web-application, webserver, apache, url-redirection, raspberry-pi

I want to understand security implications of changing **DocumentRoot** in Apache to an installed website versus adding a **RewriteRule**.

The reason I ask this, I have a website that is installed under **/var/www/html/website/**. I initially changed the DocumentRoot to /var/www/html/website in the **000-default-le-ssl.conf** file. This however, exposed certain elements during an NMAP scan. Specifically JS and CSS files. Examples:

https://ipaddress/nextcloud/core/js/contactsmenu.js?v=6e38f86c-7
https://IPaddress/nextcloud/core/css/guest.css?v=6e38f86c-7

and few more.

I considered this insecure behavior and hence added the following as part of the 000-default-le-ssl.conf configuration file.

I changed DocumentRoot to /var/www/html and added:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule (.*) /nextcloud/ [R=301]
```

Hence my question, is there any security benifit of changing DocumentRoot to default and adding a redirect or is the end result the same?

Also, I know this is product specific (nextcloud), but should such files be visible?

Comment: *"I considered this insecure behavior..."* - for what reason? Just because something comes up from a nmap scan does not mean that this is a problem. With this argument you should probably shutdown your whole server since nmap will report the port as open otherwise. At the end all what is relevant is if there are sensitive data accessible by unauthorized users or can unauthorized users do otherwise harm - which has nothing to do with DocumentRoot per se.

Comment: You're right, I'm not aware of specific reason(s) and hence based on my limited knowledge I called it insecure. If you can help me understand genuineness of the threat, I'd be thankful.

Comment: It will only fool nmap and it's something small but better than nothing.